# Cannot redirect logged in users to home page in django

Tags: python, django

When I log in I cannot get the site to redirect me to the home page. Instead, it simply logs me out again.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.home, name='home'),
    path("accounts/login/", views.login, name="login"),
    path("accounts/register/", views.register, name="register"),
    path("accounts/", include("django.contrib.auth.urls"), name="accounts"),
    path("search/", views.search),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, template_name="home.html", context={"session":request.session.items})

def login(request):
    if (request.method == "POST"):
        form= UserLoginForm(request.POST)
        user = authenticate(username=request.POST["username"], password=request.POST["password"])
        if (user.is_authenticated):
            user.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("home", kwargs={"user":user}))
        else:
            return render(request, "registration/register.html", {})
    else:
        return render(request, "registration/login.html", {})
```

Then I handled logging in and registering by inheriting the default classes used for that. So this is what it looks like:

**forms.py**

```
class NewUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=32, help_text='username')
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email", "password1", "password2")

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(NewUserForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
    

class UserLoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserLoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
    username = UsernameField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': '', 'id': 'hello'}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': '',
            'id': 'hi',
        }
    ))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email", "password1", "password2")

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(NewUserForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

Lastly the error is:

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'home' with keyword arguments '{'user': <User: mytest>}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['\\Z']
```

Comment: In the 'urls.py' file, the home view is defined as: `path("", views.home, name='home')`. This means the URL does not take any argument. However, you're trying to call it with the user argument in your Reverse `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("home", kwargs={"user":user}))`.

Comment: Thanks @Luci, how do I modify this so that it retains the session for the user?